# Send mail via G-mail using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created VBA code so all added mail addresses receive a report from Outlook.

Can I configure Gmail here?

```
Private Sub Send_Report_Mail_Click()
    Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
    Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
    Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
    Email_Subject = "Monthly Meeting Report"
    Email_Send_From = "abc@xyz.com"
    Email_Send_To = "abc@xyz.com"
    Email_Cc = "abc@xyz.com"
    Email_Bcc = ""
    Email_Body = "Hi Guys please checkout the monthly meeting report herewith...  :)"
    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
        With Mail_Single
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .CC = Email_Cc
        .BCC = Email_Bcc
        .Body = Email_Body
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\AH0130347\Desktop\Meeting_Home.xlsm")
        .Send
        End With
    debugs:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. But you have to use *CDO* (Collaboration Data Object). [See this link perhaps.](http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/12/how-to-send-an-email-using-excel-macro-from-gmail-or-yahoo/) Or better yet [this one](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm)

Comment: this famous ([Wikipedia article as a proof of famousness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILOVEYOU)) working code may be also useful: http://www.cexx.org/loveletter.htm